# Why is the electric field operator normalized by a volume?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, electric-fields

I came across the following definition of the electric field operator:

[image]

But I am not sure what this $V$, the "volume of a box", is about. It seems to enter the discussion in order to have standing waves, but surely we could just assume an arbitrary standing wave without invoking a "box".

Why do we have that $V$ parameter in this definition? What happens if $V\rightarrow\infty$ (and $E_0\rightarrow 0$)? No QFT if you don't have a box at hand?

Comment: Well, think about how you obtain a classical field theory: A lattice of coupled particles in a box, and then the distance between the particles goes to zero as the box size goes to infinity (often called "the continuum limit"). A QFT is obtained in much the same way.

Comment: I edited the title of the post. You get better responses when the title is as specific as possible. [This meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) has great tips.

Comment: But here, if I let $V$ go to infinity, I get 0! Is that not a problem?

Comment: Also, unless there is a way to eliminate $V$, what value do I choose for $V$ when I don't obviously have a "box" to play with? That degree of freedom lets me have the theory say anything I want, doesn't it?